# How to add button and total dynamically?

Tags: android, listview, button, android-listview

How can I add a **Total** `TextView` inside `ListView`, as well as a **Save** `Button` under the `ListView`, dynamically?

---

**Total** is to be displayed similar to the following image. (note: not my data representation)

[image: Example of a ListView Total Row]

---

#### Activity A (Code Snippet)

```
long as=0; // for total
long bs=0;    

@Override 
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    // receive from B
    switch (requestCode) 
    {
        case 0:
            result = data.getStringExtra("text"); // holds value (34,24)
            name = data.getStringExtra("a"); // Project
            as = as+Long.parseLong(result); // For total amount
            Text = "  " + name + " " + "RM" + result + ""; // display in listView

            if (mClickedPosition == -1) {
                //add new list
                m_listItems.add(Text);
                m_listBitmapItems.add(Global.img);
            } else {
                // edit listView value and image
                m_listItems.set(mClickedPosition, Text);  
                m_listBitmapItems.set(mClickedPosition, Global.img);
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listV.setAdapter(adapter);

            break;
        case 1:  // Another name
            result = data.getStringExtra("text");
            name = data.getStringExtra("a");
            description = data.getStringExtra("c");
            bs = bs + Long.parseLong(result);
            Log.d("FIRST", "result:" + result);
            Text = "  " + name + "  " + "RM" + result + "";

            if (mClickedPosition == -1)
            {
                m_listItems.add(Text);
            } else {
                m_listItems.set(mClickedPosition, Text);
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listV.setAdapter(adapter);

            break;
        }
    }

    long samount = as + bs;
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), samount + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

#### Activity A (Rendered Output)

[image: Rendered Output]

Here I would like to add a **Total** `TextView` with value `58` (output as `RM58`), as well as a **Save** `Button`.

---

I am using the following xml files.

#### a.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:padding="10dp" 
        android:text="@string/text" 
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/listView1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

#### claims.xml (inside the listView)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="101dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Thanks.

Comment: @MrsEd how about the total ?

Comment: you should review the `ListView` control documentation, but generally speaking.. you should consider the behavior of the control.. those are other controls, thus they should be represented as such by adding them after the ListView control. The data needs to be aggregated over in another manner..

Comment: Can provide some link or example? I have no idea on this...Thanks

Comment: @BrettCaswell Could you help me? please

Comment: @Tony, I don't have enough experience with Android to provide a comprehensive solution; having said that, following your logic in `onActivityResult` (which seems to be an event handler), you're assigning the parsed value of `result` to `as`, which is defined as `long as` in outter function scope. it should be `as = as + Long.parseLong(result);` or `as += Long.parseLong(result);` (if permitted).

Comment: @Tony, the `long as` may not even be necessary, however.... For, `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` can probably be (or is already) handled by a method. Provided you are actually using (updating) a dataset, Assigning **Total** to the `Textbox` Text property would be better handled in an `onDataSetChanged` method handler.

Comment: Thanks, you have solved my first issue :)...

Comment: but I still looking for the answer on how to add `total` and `button` dynamically

Comment: @MrsEd I already know how to add button dynamically.

Comment: @MrsEd Once it has a `list`, the total will be appeared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following footer.xml file to res/layout http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    // Format as you please
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Total" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In your activity create and initialise the following variables.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
ViewGroup footer = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, listView,
            false);

// You can add this when an item is added and remove it if the list is empty.
listView.addFooterView(footer, null, false);


tv = (TextView)footer.findViewById(R.id.tv);

// Update the text.
tv.append("t/"+ results.toString());
```

As mentioned in the comments, you can either use `long total` as a static class member and update it with the results value total+=results; taking care to reset the value to zero or decrement it if an item is removed from the list.

The other way is to loop through the items in your list, parsing the items to the object and getting the particular value of type `long` from each object and summing them as you go.

As you are now able to dynamically add your button, I'll add briefly for other users browsing, set the buttons visibility to GONE, so that the element does not displace the layout when it is not visible, HIDDEN makes the element not visible, but the space taken by the element affects the layout (and sometimes this is useful). Then the button visibility is dynamically changed to VISIBLE when an item is added to the list, and back to GONE when the list is cleared.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:text="button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Visibility.html

Comment: This is how I add the **save** button dynamically. [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33797602/remove-the-line-in-listview?noredirect=1#comment55361391_33797602)

Comment: So I need to use different `xml` ? One is for `button` and another is `total(footer.xml)` ?